# javascript verify the result of ajax request in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i've been struggling with this issue for a while... I want to verify the result of an ajax request in a function. I know that the ajax call doesn't end when the function ends, but I don't know how to make the above sample piece of code work.

```
function verify(data)
{
  if(data > 5)
     return false;
  else
  {
     // ajax call
     if(ajax response == "")
       return  false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the rest of your code i.e the xhr request.

Comment: it's not something specific, I've ran into this issue a few times, but I didn't knew how to develop it. I think this can be solved with callbacks. You said about xhr request; I've used xmlhttp for a while, but I switched to jQuery since the sintax it's much smaller and cleaner. Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `verify` as the **callback** for your ajax call.

If you're using jQuery, it would look something like:

```
$.ajax('foo.asmx/Method',  { dataType: 'json', success: verify });
```

If you'd like to use jQuery to set up a global ajax handler for any call, you can use the [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) function.

If you're doing this natively, with an actual xhr object, I think you need something like this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        verify(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I'm using jQuery. But what if I have more than one ajax call? I have merge them into one?

Comment: Specify whichever callback you'd like for each ajax call.  If both use verify, then you can specify verify for both calls.

Comment: I think I understand now how this works... hope it will work. Thank you!

Comment: @flaviu - glad to hear it - also check out my edit if you want something to be set up globally